# How to combine multiple textbox values into 1 textbox, except skip empty values and vbNewLine

Tags: excel, vba

I'm using `vbNewLine` to format a staked set of values within a textbox, just to be visually neat.

The gist of what I want -- to press CommandButton1 to transfer contents of Textbox 1-4 to Textbox5; however, I'd want it to skip any empty textboxes in 1-4 to avoid the empty space it creates in Textbox5 due to `vbNewLine`.

I know this doesn't work, but the general idea is this:

`Textbox5 = Textbox1.Text & vbNewLine & Textbox2.Text & vbNewLine & Textbox3.Text & vbNewLine & Textbox4.Text`

I've tried to think of IF textbox empty statements, textbox greater than " " statements to count or not count values, but have unfortunately failed. Thank you in advance!

[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VnFpp.png)

Comment: Always best to show the code you tried

Comment: May try `TextBox5.Value = IIf(TextBox1.Value = "", "", TextBox1.Value & vbCrLf) & IIf(TextBox2.Value = "", "", TextBox2.Value & vbCrLf) & IIf(TextBox3.Value = "", "", TextBox3.Value & vbCrLf) & IIf(TextBox4.Value = "", "", TextBox4.Value & vbCrLf)`

Comment: Ahmed AU, that works brilliantly! Thank you so much!